# TeamCity copying artifacts from one agent to another

Tags: teamcity

I'm extremely new to TeamCity and need to copy files from one TeamCity agent to another. I'm basically looking for some conceptual direction so I can start researching on how to accomplish the following:

1. Currently have a TeamCity Agent which builds program and creates corresponding artifacts. I need to copy these artifacts to another TeamCity Agent machine.
2. I'm getting acquainted with the build steps, we are using a commandline build runner. So I'll need to setup the build step for copying files via commandline--any hints on how to get started is greatly appreciated.

I apologize for any conceptual or term errors. I guess this is why I'm posting this question.

Answer (score 4):

Kme,

In case you want to re-use the results of one build in another (e.g., run tests using results of compilation), you should take a look at two things:

- Publish your build artifacts to server (more details [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Artifact))
- Download an artifact from server before build starts (more details [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Dependent+Build#DependentBuild-ArtifactDependency))

This will allow TeamCity to ensure that artifacts arrive at correct agent at correct moment of time. Also TeamCity will track usages of such artifacts.

Comment: Looks like artifact dependencies are for downloading artifacts from another build. Is there a recommendation on getting artifacts in the same build but on a different agent?

Comment: As documentation states: `A dependency can be configured on a previous build of the same build configuration`
Just use same build configuration as the source.